# writeToPath:atomically: - not sure why this is failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata

This is the code i have. The NSDictionary did used to be something, but i've temporarily removed that, when trying to find the problem.

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Entries/"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL isDirectory = NO;
    BOOL directoryExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isDirectory];
    if (!directoryExists) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }

    if ([self.pathName isEqualToString:@""] || self.pathName == nil) {
    self.pathName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.JEntry", [JMedia generateUuidString]];
    }

    NSString  *entryPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.pathName];

    NSDictionary *dictionary;

    NSLog(@"entrypath: %@", entryPath);

    BOOL success = [dictionary writeToFile:entryPath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"success: %i", success);
```

NSLog:

```
entrypath: /var/mobile/Applications/1B838285-8326-427A-8AC5-0D5567C3CD81/Documents/Entries/70AFCF6D-540E-436E-9989-68793500E35B.JEntry
success: 0
```

Comment: Have you checked the sim's documents directory to see if the file exists?

Comment: The `[JMedia generate UuidString]` method brings back a totally random string, so it can't already exist.

Comment: At the moment `dictionary` is nil, so this is never going to work.

Comment: Can you post the original code before you remove the value of `dictionary`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that `dictionary` contains items that are not property list objects as the [documentaion](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHDBHDB) says:

> This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and **returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects**, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

Comment: I thought of that, which is why i made the NSDictionary not contains any objects. So i know that isn't the problem.

Comment: No. In your current code, the `NSDictionary` is not a dictionary that doesn't contain any object, it is `nil`. That's why you get `success: 0` now.